# Strange react-native Version Number When Running from Local `node_modules`

Tags: react-native

When I run `react-native --version` from the global installation, it reports to me what I consider to be an accurate version number, like this:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.4
```

However, when I run `yarn react-native --version` (from the local installation at `node_modules`, it reports the version number simply as `3.2.1`.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It’s possible to have separate installs for those modules. As an aside, this is one reason why global installs are frowned upon. It can get confusing and they don’t auto-synchronize. As long as it’s not causing problems, I wouldn’t be too concerned.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeS. As it turns out, I didn't have a global install of react native. I had the react-native cli installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The definitive way to find the react native version number for your local project is to run `react-native info` locally. This can be done one of the following ways:

```
npm run react-native info
yarn react-native info
```

In answer to the original question: "Why am I seeing the strange version number?", here is my analysis:

As it turns out, I did not have react-native installed globally. I had react-native-cli installed globally.

If you open Terminal and `cd` to some random directory and run `react-native --version` (assuming you also have `react-native-cli` installed), the response will look something like this:

```sh
$ react-native --version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: n/a - not inside a React Native project directory
```

If you then cd to a react-native project's root folder and run `react-native --version`, it will return the actual version number of that local project.

However, when you run `yarn react-native --version` from the root folder of a react-native project, what actually gets returned is the version of the `@react-native-community/cli` installation. (You get the same result if you run `npx react-native --version` or if you look in the package.json file of the local `@react-native-community/cli` installation in `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli`.

So, long story short, if you want to know the exact react-native version your local project is using, use `react-native info` (easy) or open up `./node_modules/react-native/package.json` and it will tell you the version number.